# How to pass dynamic value to timeWindow(<dynamic_Time>) in flink

Tags: api, apache-flink

```
DataStream<Sensor> processStream = inputDataStream.filter(new TransientFallFilter());

DataStream<Event> outputStream = processStream.keyBy("k", "s").timeWindow(Time.minutes(2)).apply(new TransientRiseEventSelect());
```

Is there possibility or API Where I can pass a dynamic time value to timeWindow(t) function? I have a requirement where the time frame changes according to the key.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not supported by the default time-windows of the DataStream API.
However, it should be possible implement such behavior with a custom `WindowAssigner` and `Trigger`. A `WindowAssigner` assigns records to windows and the `Trigger` decides when to compute the window.

See the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html) for details.

Comment: Could you provide any reference or example? @fabian